# How do I find the complexity of this recursive algorithm? Replace pattern in string with binary number

Tags: algorithm, recursion, time-complexity, complexity-theory, backtracking

This algorithm essentially finds the star (*) inside a given binary string, and replaces it with 0 and also 1 to output all the different combinations of the binary string.

I originally thought this algorithm is O(2^n), however, it seems to me that that only takes into account the number of stars (*) inside the string. What about the length of the string? Since if there are no stars in the given string, it should technically still be linear, because the amount of recursive calls depends on string length, but my original O(2^n) does not seem to take that into account as it would become O(1) if n = 0.

How should I go about finding out its time and space complexity? Thanks.

Code:

```
static void RevealStr(StringBuilder str, int i) {
    //base case: prints each possibility when reached
    if(str.length() == i) {
        System.out.println(str);
        return;
    }
    //recursive step if wild card (*) found
    if(str.charAt(i) == '*') {
        //exploring permutations for 0 and 1 in the stack frame
        for(char ch = '0'; ch <= '1'; ch++) {
            //making the change to our string
            str.setCharAt(i, ch);
            //recur to reach permutations
            RevealStr(str, i+1);
            //undo changes to backtrack
            str.setCharAt(i, '*');
        }
        return;
    }
    else
        //if no wild card found, recur next char
        RevealStr(str, i+1);
}
```

Edit: I am currently thinking of something like, O(2^s + l) where s is the number of stars and l the length of the string.

Comment: it is `O(2^l)` I guess, since the number of stars is at most the length of string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea of Big-O notation is to give an estimate of an upperbound, i.e. if the order of an algorithm is O(N^4) runtime it simply means that algorithm can't do any **worse** than that.

Lets say, there maybe an algorithm of order O(N) runtime but we can still say it is O(N^2). Since O(N) never does any worse than O(N^2). But then in computational sense we want the estimate to be as close and tight as it will give us a better idea of how well an algorithm actually performs.

In your current example, both O(2^N) and O(2^L), N is length of string and L is number of *, are **valid upperbounds**. But since O(2^L) gives a better idea about algorithm and its dependence on the presence of * characters, O(2^L) is better and tighter estimate (as L<=N) of the algorithm.

**Update:** The space complexity is implementation dependant. In your current implementation, assuming StringBuilder is passed by reference and there are no copies of strings made in each recursive call, the space complexity is indeed O(N), i.e. the size of recursive call stack. If it is passed by value and it is copied to stack every time before making call, the overall complexity would then be O(N * N), i.e. (O(max_number_of_recursive_calls * size_of_string)), since copy operation cost is O(size_of_string).

Comment: Thanks. Would the space complexity then be O(n) where n is simply length of string? It seems that although having more stars creates more recursive calls, only a maximum of n stacks exists at once. Edit: actually, there seems to be 4 recursive calls when there's only 2 stars in a given string ("**")

Comment: Actually, I started counting at 1 instead of 0 for the level of recursive calls. It does seem there are always n calls where n is string length.

Comment: I assume StringBuilder is that of Java, in that case it is indeed O(N). Had it been String of Java, it would have been O(N^2).

Answer (score 1):

To resolve this we can do a manual run:

**Base:** n=1

```
RevealStr("*", 1)
```

It meets the criteria for the first if, we only ran this once for output `*`

**Next:** n=2

```
RevealStr("**", 1)
  RevealStr("0*", 2)
    RevealStr("00", 2)
    RevealStr("01", 2)
  RevealStr("1*", 2)
    RevealStr("10", 2)
    RevealStr("11", 2)
```

**Next:** n=3

```
RevealStr("***", 1)
  RevealStr("0**", 2)
    RevealStr("00*", 2)
      RevealStr("000", 3)
      RevealStr("001", 3)
    RevealStr("01*", 2)
      RevealStr("010", 3)
      RevealStr("011", 3)
  RevealStr("1**", 2)
    RevealStr("10*", 2)
      RevealStr("100", 3)
      RevealStr("101", 3)
    RevealStr("11*", 2)
      RevealStr("110", 3)
      RevealStr("111", 3)
```

You can see that with n=2, `RevealStr` was called 7 times, while with n=3 it was called 15. This follows the function `F(n)=2^(n+1)-1`

For the worst case scenario, the complexity seems to be O(2^n) being n the number of stars

Comment: Thanks. However, should we not account for the number of characters in the string? It seems to me that the recursive call is performed whether or not the character is a star. Are there not two variables to count here for the complexity? If there are no stars in the string, the algo isn't O(1), it still is linear to the string length right?

Comment: This is the worst case scenario (the case with the most amount of calls) which is all stars (*), since your algorithm has 2 paths, it won’t always follow the same path. The same happens when sorting an array, you have the best scenario (usually the already sorted) and the worst (where you will have to do the biggest amount of operations [swaps])

Comment: Edit: after reading your comment more carefully, you are right, it will depend on two variables the length of the string (L) and the number of starts (S). If s=0, the algorithm will be O(n) (best case), if s=L it is O(2^s) and depending on the different values it can range between them